# Cómo hacer varias preguntas en una sola en Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

[image: Google Forms]

Buenas tardes, me gustaría saber cómo poder agregar tres preguntas en una sola (tal como muestra la imagen) en Google Forms
Y si son tres preguntas, cómo se puede disminuir de tamaño el título de la pregunta? 
Saludos

Comment: Ese formulario es tuyo o lo viste en alguna parte? porque depende del contrato que tengas de la suite de gmail se te habilitan algunas opciones y otras no, tal como esa de concatenar varias opciones a un enunciado

Comment: No es mio, tengo que hacer algo parecido con Google Forms, pero no encontraba la opción para hacerlo igual. Entonces debe ser que lo hicieron con una cuenta de pago de Google, gracias

Comment: Igual no es muy recomendable si vas a trabajar luego con los datos, ya que estos se van a una hoja de calculo donde al final sera el mismo resultado y cada respuesta te quedara en una columna, solo te estarias desgastando en el frontend.

Answer (score 0):

No sé cómo obtuviste la captura de pantalla, pero no parece ser tomada de un formulario de Google "natural", independientemente de si corresponde a una cuenta común de Google o a una de G Suite.

Los formularios de Google además de preguntas pueden incluir títulos y secciones. Podrías usar uno de estos para agrupar las preguntas de tus formularios.